# Updating to Firebase Android version 15.0.0, signs users out

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

When Updating `com.google.firebase` and `com.google.android.gms` from `11.8.0` to `15.0.0`, our signed-in users are getting signed out. On checking, we are able to confirm that `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` returns `null`.

A few other things i was able to confirm:

1. This has been confirmed for Phone Auth and Email and Password Auth
2. If I:

   1. Sign in to app v1 with library versions v11.8.0
   2. Update to app v2 with library versions v15.0.0

   **I see myself signed OUT (as mentioned above).**

   3. Do not bother to sign in again in this v2
   4. Update to app v3 with library versions set back to v11.8.0

   **I see myself signed in.**
3. If I:

   1. Sign in to app v1 with library versions v15.0.0
   2. Update to app v2 with library versions set back to v11.8.0

   **I see myself signed in.**

   3. Now if i continue and, update to app v3 with library versions v15.0.0

   **I still see myself signed in.**
4. I was able to reproduce this issue also if i upgrade from v12.0.1 to v15.0.0
5. This is most likely an issue with the library itself (and not my code) since i was able to reproduce this issue using [Firebase Android Auth Quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth)

Does anyone else face this? Is there something i am missing? Did i miss something relevant in the v15.0.0 [Release Notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)?

Answer (score 3):

I reached out to firebase support and they were also able to reproduce the aforementioned faulty behaviour. Turns out this is a an issue in v15.0.0 library itself.

Kyle from Firebase Support [Apr 25, 2018]:

> After discussing this more with our engineers, they told me that the fix will be rolled-out on the next release (next version) soon. I can't provide the exact timeline for this but you may keep an eye out on the release notes for future updates with Firebase Android SDK.

**Update [May 7, 2018]**

Updating my dependencies from v11.8.0 directly to [updates to Firebase Android SDK released on May 2, 2018](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions) resolve the aforementioned issue.

Comment: I also faced the same issue...I just want to make sure you updated the app from v11.8.0 to v15.0.2 rite ?

Comment: @Rajesh Starting from May 2, 2018, not all firebase libraries have the same version numbers. So it depends, which firebase feature it is that you are talking about. Please look here for the latest versions of each feature: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions

Answer (score 0):

We had the exact same issue!
Going with the latest dependencies fixed everything!

Comment: Btw, in our case, that fixed most of the issues, but not all. Updating to latest, we faced other issues where the `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getToken` async call would not invoke any callback, for those user's who updated our app (but not those who installed first time after the above fix). Additionally, FirebaseUI for Storage also broke. These issues were also later confirmed by the support team.